# Detect if Image inside Imageview overlaps Textview

Tags: android, android-imageview, textview, overlap

I have the following Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.myapp.imagezoom.ImageViewTouch
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="2"/>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/loading"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

As you can see there is a zoomable ImageView. The TextView is shown below the ImageView as long as it is not zoomed. If the user zooms into the ImageView it is on top of it.
How can I detect if the showing ImageView overlaps the TextView to show a background to the TextView?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add to your `ImageViewTouch` class a property called `isZoomed` and then just verify if is true or false into a custom override method or into an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and set the background of the TextView or whatever you want there.

To learn more about creating custom override methods I suggest you to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13105189/start-dialog-for-result), it simply explains how to do it.